# What's correct - 'repeat us' vs 'repeat to us'?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice

> They used to repeat **to** us: ‘Seek and ye shall find'.

vs

> They used to repeat us: ‘Seek and ye shall find'. ?

Or maybe both are well? And 'repeat' is well or should I write 'keep telling'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They used to repeat to us: ‘Seek and ye shall find'.

This is the correct version. These are some lines, or in this case, a line that they are repeating to you (the whole group). What are they doing? - **Repeating**. To who are they doing it to? - **You**.

> They used to repeat us: ‘Seek and ye shall find'.

This certainly sounds like someone repeated ***you***, like made a clone of you. That certainly, I believe, is not the case.

Also on the context of using the word 'repeat', it is indeed a good choice rather than using the words 'keep telling'.

---

If you want to use an alternative, you can consider the word 'reiterate'. However in the context of a story or a paraphrase, the word 'repeat' stands out more as compared to 'reiterate'.

If you are, in case, telling a story, then of course the word 'retelling' is more apt.

> They used to retell us, the story of the great men, who stood and fought for honour.

**Note**: 'Retell' won't use the preposition 'to'.